# Python - PyQt4, Scaping, will not recognize xpath address

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, pyqt, pyqt4

I am scrapping this site (below) with PyQt. For some reason the archive_links.xpath returns for the preceding /div tag, but will not return anything for the /ul tag. Using "inspect" on Chrome I can see the tags. What am I missing here?

I'm using python3.4 and PyQt4-4.11.4, if it matters

Any help would be appreciated!

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *  
from PyQt4.QtCore import *  
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *  
from lxml import html 

url = r'https://www.seedinvest.com/dstld/series.a.2'

class Render(QWebPage):  
    def __init__(self, url):  
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)  
        QWebPage.__init__(self)  
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)  
        self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))  
        self.app.exec_()  

    def _loadFinished(self, result):  
        self.frame = self.mainFrame()  
        self.app.quit()  

r = Render(url)  
result = r.frame.toHtml()

archive_links = html.fromstring(str(result.encode('utf-8')))

archive_links.xpath('//*[@id="site-content"]/header/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/ul')
```

Thanks,

Comment: All of the code following the `r = Render(url)` line needs to go in the `loadFinished` handler. That is, you need to wait for the page to fully load before accessing the html.

Comment: Sorry, So do you mean before the self.app.quit()?

Comment: Yes. And obviously `r.frame` is `self.frame`.

Comment: @ekhumoro, That still did not provide a tag/element for that xpath.

Comment: For whatever reason, the page is not fully loading before the xpath query is run. If you write `result` to a file, you'll probably find that some of the tags just aren't there. Presumably, there's some javascript that is supposed to insert those tags when the page loads - but it fails for some obscure reason.